# Is it possible to use a PIR detector to switch something on and keep it on without a microprocessor?

Tags: switches, pir

When a PIR detector switches something on e.g. a 12V light, I know I could use a microprocessor to keep it on or do anything that I choose to programme.

If I didn't want to use a microprocessor, how can I switch a 12V something on and then have it remain on even after the PIR detector has reset?

Basically, I am looking for the most simple circuit I can get away with, for no other reason than trying to not over-complicate things.

Comment: You don't need a micro with a PIR sensor. Many outdoor lights with a sensor just use a simple (RC based) timer, often this is already part of the PIR circuit. For hobby purposes uou could use an NE555 timer. The reason why today you see micros used everywhere in products is because a micro can be bought for  a couple of cents which is cheaper than a timer chip which needs a resistor and a capacitor.

Comment: look up a "latch circuit", or use a relay to feed the output back into the input. or set the timer pot on the PIR to max, that will make it stay on for a LONG time.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the "latch circuit" pointer.  This is a dumb alarm PIR I salvaged, so it doesn't have a timer, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PIR detector output can activate an electromechanical relay (such via an open collector transistor) then, one of the spare contacts in the relay can be used to short out the open collector transistor and keep the relay self-activated.

Alternatively, If the PIR detector has a voltage output then it can be diode-orred with the spare relay contact in order to keep the relay activated when the PIR signal falls away.

Another contact on the relay can switch 12 volts to whatever load is required.